# Mysql group results found in different rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot, resultset

I have a problem that I can't solve myself.

I have the following table in Mysql (result of some join) that describes all the events

event_table:

| ID | Odl_ID | Evt_ID | Evt_Desc | Evt_Date | Link_1 | Link_2 | Start_Time | End_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | Start | 2021-08-06 10:15:00 | Null | Null | 2021-08-06 10:15:00 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | Start | 2021-08-06 12:15:00 | Null | Null | 2021-08-06 12:18:00 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | Finish | 2021-08-06 14:15:00 | Null | Null | 2021-08-06 10:15:00 | 2021-08-06 14:15:00 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | Generate PDF 1 | 2021-08-06 14:25:00 | C:\Path1 | Null |  |  |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | Generate PDF 2 | 2021-08-06 14:25:00 | Null | C:\Path2 |  |  |
| 6 | 2 | 0 | Finish | 2021-08-06 14:35:00 | Null | Null | 2021-08-06 10:18:00 | 2021-08-06 18:15:00 |
| 7 | 2 | 0 | Generate PDF 1 | 2021-08-06 18:25:00 | C:\Path3 | Null |  |  |
| 8 | 2 | 0 | Generate PDF 2 | 2021-08-06 18:25:00 | Null | C:\Path4 |  |  |

And I want to create a view like this that group the Odl_ID and present all the events found in different rows (like the event date, Link_1, etc).

The resulting table that I'm tring to achive:

| ID | Odl_ID | Evt_Date | Link_1 | Link_2 | Start_Time | End_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-08-06 10:15:00 | C:\Path1 | C:\Path2 | 2021-08-06 10:15:00 | 2021-08-06 14:15:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-08-06 12:15:00 | C:\Path3 | C:\Path4 | 2021-08-06 12:18:00 | 2021-08-06 18:15:00 |

How can I solve the problem?
I can't figure out how to do it, I tried looking for pivot table but I haven't figured out the problem yet. Thanks

Comment: *event_table* This table is wrong - the columns with the same name are present. Assign different names to them.

Comment: If your data matches "the same values for Evt_Date, Start_Time, End_Time for all rows with the same Odl_ID" and "only one row in Link_1 (1) and in Link_1 (2) withing a group contains a value" then group by Evt_Date, Start_Time, End_Time and Odl_ID, and get MAX  for each Link_1.

Comment: Edited second coloumn name

Comment: @alessandro.todisco as per your sample data contains 4 types of event description like start, finish, gen pdf1, gen pdf2. If any one missing then those opl_id info will show or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that might work, but don't know if it's fully
correct / maybe there's a better solution for that

```
SELECT Odl_Id,
min(Start_time) Start_time,
max(End_time) End_time,
max(Evt_ID) Evt_ID, 
max(Link_1) Link_1,
max(Link_2) Link_2
 FROM view_2
 Group by ODL_Id;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `MIN(Start_time) Start_time` and `Odl_ID` instead of `ODL`?

Comment: @Sam020 you're right. I adapted the table, but while copying I forgot this

Comment: I think you missed the `ODL`in the `Group by` ;) And I still think it should be `MIN(Start_time) Start_time` because you want the "oldest" start_time as your example of the endresult shows.

Comment: thanks @Sam020, I've updated as suggested